# how to fix error E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, dpkg, nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mawk (1.3.3-17ubuntu3) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/nodejs': Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing package mawk (--configure):
 installed mawk package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Setting up gawk (1:4.1.4+dfsg-1build1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/nodejs': Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing package gawk (--configure):
 installed gawk package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mawk
 gawk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The error message clearly states (twice) that you have a problem with /usr/bin/nodejs to investigate and fix. Do so.

Comment: but how to fix that issue i googled and almost try everything but its not fixing.... @user535733

Comment: You asked about apt. The answer is to fix your nodejs first. If you want to ask about how to troubleshoot and fix nodejs, then either edit the question or open a new question. AskUbuntu is a Question/Answer site, not a conversation forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move problematic NodeJS executable out the way with

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/nodejs ~/nodejs_broken
```

then resume your operations with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and reinstall NodeJS with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs
```